# How to apply media query in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, frontend, media-queries

Media Query for mobile devices -

How to apply media query in **next js**   globally so that it becomes responsive for all type mobile-devices.

I want to apply media query in my next website so that that i can make it responsive how am i going to do it?

As beginner Web Developer.

Sample Generated Code -

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
      
<head>
    <title>Media Query</title>
      
    <style>
          
        /* Media Query for Mobile Devices */
        @media (max-width: 480px) {
            body {
                background-color: red;
            }
        }
          
        /* Media Query for low resolution  Tablets, Ipads */
        @media (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 767px) {
            body {
                background-color: yellow;
            }
        }
          
        /* Media Query for Tablets Ipads portrait mode */
        @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px){
            body {
                background-color: blue;
            }
        }
          
        /* Media Query for Laptops and Desktops */
        @media (min-width: 1025px) and (max-width: 1280px){
            body {
                background-color: green;
            }
        }
          
        /* Media Query for Large screens */
        @media (min-width: 1281px) {
            body {
                background-color: white;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>
  
<body style = "text-align:center;">
    <h1>Generated Media Query </h1>
    <h2>Media Query</h2>
</body>
  
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are willing to use a third-party library, MUI has exactly what you need in [useMediaQuery](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-use-media-query/):

```
import * as React from 'react'
import useMediaQuery from '@mui/material/useMediaQuery'

export default function SimpleMediaQuery()
{
  const matches = useMediaQuery('(min-width:600px)')

  return <span>{`(min-width:600px) matches: ${matches}`}</span>
}
```

See the docs linked above for more examples of how to use it.

If you want to avoid another library, here's a simple custom hook:

```
export const useMediaQuery = (width) =>
{
  const [targetReached, setTargetReached] = useState(false)

  const updateTarget = useCallback((e) =>
  {
    if (e.matches) setTargetReached(true)
    else setTargetReached(false)
  }, [])

  useEffect(() =>
  {
    const media = window.matchMedia(`(max-width: ${width}px)`)
    media.addEventListener('change', updateTarget)

    // Check on mount (callback is not called until a change occurs)
    if (media.matches) setTargetReached(true)

    return () => media.removeEventListener('change', updateTarget)
  }, [])

  return targetReached
}
```

Usage:

```
// 600px
const matches = useMediaQuery(600)
```